# What is silly with my Ansible syntax? when I call a list_item I am told it does not exist

Tags: yaml, ansible

So I am trying to simply return '/opt/omeka/apps'/ but despite being returned by the debug statement in the prior statement returning what I am looking for I get the responce that it does not exist.

I assume there is a silly syntactical error here and just looking for correction.

**var.yml**

```
omeka_cache_base: /opt/omeka
omeka_cache:
  - app: "{{ omeka_cache_base }}/apps"
  - plugins: "{{ omeka_cache_base }}/plugins"
  - theme: "{{ omeka_cache_base }}/themes"
```

**role.yml**

```
- name: debug
  debug: var=omeka_cache
- name: download applications files
  unarchive: 
    src:  "http://omeka.org/files/omeka-{{ inst.value.version }}.zip"
    copy: no
    dest: "{{ omeka_cache.app }}"
```

**Ansible Returns**

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
       ok: [localhost] => {
           "omeka_cache": [
        {
            "app": "/opt/omeka/apps"
        }, 
        {
            "plugins": "/opt/omeka/plugins"
        }, 
        {
            "theme": "/opt/omeka/themes"
        }
           ]
       }

       TASK [download applications files] *********************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'list object' has no attribute 'app'"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created a list, when what you want is a dict. try storing your var like this instead.

```
omeka_cache:
  app: "{{ omeka_cache_base }}/apps"
  plugins: "{{ omeka_cache_base }}/plugins"
  theme: "{{ omeka_cache_base }}/themes"
```

then `"{{ omeka_cache.app }}"` should work

Comment: notice I have removed the dashes in front of the `app`, `plugins`, and `theme` keys

Comment: that did make it work however when running with `with_dict` in a loop I had to use it as `{{ item.value.app }}`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like there's an array there. Try `omeka_cache[0].app`. I used jq to parse your debug, then played around with it to confirm:

```
>cat t.json
        {
           "omeka_cache": [
        {
            "app": "/opt/omeka/apps"
        }, 
        {
            "plugins": "/opt/omeka/plugins"
        }, 
        {
            "theme": "/opt/omeka/themes"
        }
           ]
       }

>jq < t.json '[.omeka_cache[0].app]'
[
  "/opt/omeka/apps"
]
```

Comment: This is a bad workaround for using the wrong type of variable for the use-case. using the correct variable type is much better